# Facebook API: definitely NOT possible to get pool results (votes)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

talking about Facebook's polls:
it is confirmed that in AD 2018 the votes of a poll posted on a page are
IMPOSSIBLE to gather using the Graph API ?

Could somedody confirm this ?

thanks
cp

Comment: why did i get a downvote ? nobody ever answerd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799787/facebook-api-how-to-get-option-results-votes and i coudn't comment on that question .... so i created a new one.

Comment: You’re referring to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/question ?

Comment: yes, where it says : "You can still read the data from old questions" so if a question is created from the ui in the past, is it to consider old ? and therefore possible to get information about ?

Comment: Well `/page-id/questions` definitively doesn’t work any more, but if you have the id of a specific question object you can try and see what that returns ...

Comment: i get "Application does not have permission for this action." but as you probably know, the Graph API returns this error even if the permissions are there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to get access to polls has been removed a long time ago, as you can read here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/question
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/question_option

Comment: yes, where it says : "You can still read the data from old questions" so if a question is created from the ui in the past, is it to consider old ? and therefore possible to get information about ?

Comment: it was removed after graph api v1.0 - that´s several years ago, not sure if you are really interested in the data of polls that were created years ago...

Comment: v1.0 was deprecated in april 2015